# Link in react-router-dom removing css

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to have individual divs take me to different pages, using this code in my home.js

```
 <Link to="Subject1">
   <Product
     title="The Lean Startup"
     image="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51Zymoq7UnL._SX325_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"
   />
 </Link>

 <Link to="The Lean Startup">
   <Product
     title="The stone"
     image="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51Zymoq7UnL._SX325_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"
   />
 </Link>
 <Link to="Subject1">
   <Product
     title="The Lean Startup"
     image="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51Zymoq7UnL._SX325_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"
   />
 </Link>
```

But CSS formatting went out of shape:
[Formatting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7fR6.jpg)

This is how it looks without the link tags enclosing the product component:
[without formatting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKMrd.jpg)
How do I put links on the divs, without having any formatting changes?

Home.css:

```
.home {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1500px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.home_row {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Product.css:

```
.product {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
    min-width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.product > img {
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.product_info {
    height: 100px;
}
.product_info > p {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Hey @tinjar, Can you post the CSS please ?. Want to make sure if the some xpath is breaking your style

Comment: Sure, il edit in the Product.css and Home.css

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
const ProductLink= <Product /> //add your props using loops

<Link to="/" component={ProductLink} />
```

Comment: Sorry if this seems like a stupid qn, but by adding props using loops , do u mean having multiple const variable , each with a different set of props, and then Linking each 1? Also I tried doing this , but I got an error: ×Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. 
Code:(Il put it as another comment)

Comment: ```
function Home() {
    const ProductLink = (
        <Product
        title="Density"
        image="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.iBpQSvdrogG_wytHBuUsBAHaHa%26pid%3DApi&f=1"
        />
    );
    return (
        <div className="home">
        <div className="home_container">
            <div className="home_row">
            <Link to="/Subject1" component={ProductLink} />
```